# Wifi dead slow with WPA2 enterprise 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I am using Wifi with WPA2 enterprise protocol. Wifi is dead slow and sometimes I get 'Connection Lost' error. My university has no support for Linux and advised me to write my own wifi driver. Any other alternatives for this problem?

Wifi at my home is working fine and fast but problem is with University wifi only.

`nm-tool` output:

```
    Device: wlan0  [eduroam] -----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            brcmsmac
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        70:F1:A1:D0:18:18

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           72 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes
```

Lspci output:

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
```

uname -a:

```
Linux zaif 3.2.0-48-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 19:43:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```